# How to divide one element to another element in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

There is a couple of lists and I want to write a code thats input as DIVIDE,(fruit name) and the output is that fruits datas(5th lement/3rd element) from its list.For example one of the list is ['apple', 'a', 147, 457, 66, 119, 21, 6, 8] and the output is 0.26!

```
fruits = [['apple', 'a', 147, 457, 66, 119, 21, 6, 8], ['banana', 'b', 131, 454, 53, 108, 19, 0, 20], ['orange', 'o', 124, 454, 54, 110, 20, 2, 29], 21]
command, name = input().split()
def count_machine(command, name):
    if command == "DIVIDE" :

        for fru in fruits:
            if name == fru[0]:
                result = [fru[5] / fru[3]]
                return result

result = count_machine(command, name)
if type(result) == float:
    print("%.2f" % result)
```

Where am i doing wrong,isn't it possible to divide [fru[5] / fru[3]] two elements like this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove [] from result

```
if name == fru[0]: 
      result = [fru[5] / fru[3]]
```

Should be

```
  if name == fru[0]: 
      result = fru[5] / fru[3]
```

As your code make result a list not a float

Comment: Oh thank you,if I were to do more complex processing, do you think it would be silly for me to put it in parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

The `result` returned is a list. So, instead of checking for float type, do this to capture the float value-

```
if type(result) == list:
    print("%.2f" % result[0])
```